# SQL Where statement to check against other records in same month

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm attempting to pull records from a database but am having problems constructing the WHERE clause of the query.

I have a database full of accounts tied to a service location. Over time, accounts change but the service location never does. What I want to accomplish is a query that returns all records where a service location only had ONE account attached to it.

Here is a sample of the code, which isn't really all that close to what I need.

```
SELECT
c.account_num,
MONTH(fb.[End]) AS 'Month', 
YEAR(fb.[End]) AS 'Year', 
AVG(fb.eDays) AS 'Billing Days'

FROM 
DimServiceLocation AS sl
INNER JOIN FactBill AS fb ON fb.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
INNER JOIN DimCustomer AS c ON c.CustomerKey = fb.CustomerKey

WHERE 
AND fb.eDays IN (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35)
AND c.class_name = 'Customer' 
AND (fb.[End] > DATEADD(m, - 24, GETDATE()))
```

The WHERE clause defines the number of "eDays" (billing days) and the class_name (Customer). There are issues with doing it this way (EX: if a month has 33 billing days, it would return customers that were attached to a location for 29 days, which would not have been account holders for the entire month).

I have no idea how to accomplish this goal. I feel as though the solution may be checking service locations by specific bill periods (defined by a field called period_num) and then querying only those service locations that only had ONE account_num during that period_num.

Any help would be appreciated.

---------- **Updated** ----------

I mistakenly left out a significant portion of the original question. Apologies to those who helped. The second part of the problem is as follows:

In the original select statement, I also need to return the average *Usage* billed during an individual period across all similar service locations. These lines of code would be added:

```
SELECT
c.account_num, 
sl.[Floorplan Name],
CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,0), AVG(EUsage)) AS 'Average Electric Usage',
COUNT(DISTINCT sl.location_id) AS 'Service Locations', 
MONTH(fb.[End]) AS 'Month', 
YEAR(fb.[End]) AS 'Year', 
AVG(fb.eDays) AS 'Billing Days'
```

The final result would ideally return this information:

- The floorplan name
- The average usage during a period
- The number of service locations used to determine this average
- The month & year the period ended.
- The average number of billing days for this month (essentially, how many bill days were in this month because all accounts used should have the same number of bill days).

Again, the ultimate goal is to only consider service locations where a single account was attached during an individual billing period.

Thanks again!

---------- **Sample Results** ----------

[image: Sample Results]

Comment: One account attached to the service location _ever_, or for that billing month?

Comment: The database is constructed with the following tables:
FactBill
Customer
Service Location

Within the FactBill table, there is a CustomerKey, a ServiceLocationKey, and the period_num. The CustomerKey and ServiceLocationKey point back to the Customer and Service Location table.

FactBill is a history of all bills created. A service location can have any number of accounts. For each period_num, a service location could have 1 account or, theoretically, 1000 accounts.

I am attempting to find the instances where only one account exists for a service location within each individual period_num.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the query you need, although some sample data and expected output would definitely make things more certain:

```
SELECT
    c.account_num
    , MONTH(fb.[End]) AS 'Month', 
    , YEAR(fb.[End]) AS 'Year'
    , AVG(fb.eDays) AS 'Billing Days'
FROM DimServiceLocation AS sl
    INNER JOIN FactBill AS fb ON fb.ServiceLocationKey = sl.ServiceLocationKey
    INNER JOIN DimCustomer AS c ON c.CustomerKey = fb.CustomerKey
WHERE 
    AND fb.eDays IN (28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35)
    AND c.class_name = 'Customer' 
    AND (fb.[End] > DATEADD(m, - 24, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY c.account_num
    , MONTH(fb.[End]
    , YEAR(fb.[End])
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.account_num) = 1
```

Comment: I think you have an extra group by clause: `AVG(fb.eDays)`

Comment: My hope is to eliminate the "eDays" in the WHERE clause. I think this would allow me to do that. Right? Also, there is a second part to the problem, I will update the original question.

Comment: @johnwonderbread Please also add some sample data and expected output. That will help me a lot in making sure the query is correct.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu the question has been updated. Please let me know if you need more information.